# ASP.NET Development Server - logfile location

Tags: asp.net, rest

When trying to get a RESTful WCF service POST to work in ASP.NET we are seeing the following error message in the browser:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

We are using the ASP.NET Development Server - does anyone know where it keeps its log files?

Comment: @Adrian - make this an answer and I will up-vote it.

Comment: Somebody else did, upvote him. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider configuring WCF tracing [as described in this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You can get more details if you activate the debug messages in the web.config file inside the behavior section :

```
<serviceDebug 
            httpHelpPageEnabled="true" 
            includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"
          />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicedebugelement.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Does anything show up on the [Event Viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer)?

Answer (score 2):

The built-in development server should be outputting message to the event viewer Application log. Mine does.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to configure tracing, there are several ways how you can enable detailed error messages. Here is a [blog post](http://nsamteladze.blogspot.com/2013/07/enable-verbosely-errors-in-wcf-data.html) on how to do this.

I'm aware of 3 way to get nicer errors:

1. Set `UseVerboseErrors' in`InitializeService' method. However, this won't give you anything if your error occurs before `InitializeService' is called (which happens).
2. Set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true using an attribute before your service class.
3. Set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true using web.config.